# Remove Class From Element With Added Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to build a dropdown menu. The idea is to add class to parent and child on parent hover, and remove added class when mouse is out of both.
This is html

```
<ul>
  <li class="menuitem"></li>
  <li class="menuitem">
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menuitem"></li>
</ul>
```

And this is jquery

```
$(".menuitem").each(function(){
  $(this).hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("visible");
    $(this).find("ul").addClass("visible");
  });
});

$(".visible").each(function(){
  $(this).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("visible");
  });
});
```

Comment: why you use each? you have got class, so it's gonna work for all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hover()`  actually incorporates 2 events ... mouseenter and mouseleave. If you only provide one callback argument it gets used for both events.

If you provide 2 callbacks the first is for enter and the second is for leaving so you can do:

```
function enterEl(){
  $(this).addClass('visible').find('ul').addClass('visible');
}

function leaveEl(){
  $(this).removeClass('visible').find('ul').removeClass('visible')
}

$(".menuitem").hover(enterEl, leaveEl);
```

This is more verbose than using toggle methods but is to point out that you can do different things in the two event handlers.

This is also the same thing as doing

```
$(".menuitem") 
      .mouseenter(enterEl)
      .mouseleave(leaveEl);
```

Comment: is really just an overview of the docs but with a bit of application to your html. Keep a link to the jQuery API bookmarked. i've been using it for many years and still go there frequently

Answer (score 2):

The event handlers are bound to elements that match at the time of binding. Adding a class later doesn't make the event handler work for that class.

What you seem to be looking for, is just `toggleClass`

```
$(".menuitem").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').addBack().toggleClass("visible");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/j9brax6a/)

Comment: I love simplicity of it. But I get Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).addBack is not a function in console

Comment: And you're using a current version of jQuery, not below 1.8 ?

Comment: I had 2.2 and tried 1.12 (the one in snippet). Happens on both

Comment: That seems somewhat impossible, jQuery doesn't throw errors like that, and the fiddle works fine for me. Did you include jQuery properly, try a `document.ready` function etc

Comment: yep. everything else works. I can see it working in fiddle, and it still doesn't work on the site, which confuses me a lot. here is the url. "need a nurse" has child ul http://57f.521.mwp.accessdomain.com/jobs/licensed-vocational-nurse/

Comment: That's a Wordpress site. Firstly, you've included jQuery twice, Wordpress adds jQuery for you. Secondly, you need to use [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to add your script, and you need to use [noConflict wrappers](http://wptricks.net/jquery-noconflict-wrappers-on-wordpress/)